# Datagridview - How to set the arrow of selected row?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource, swap

I have a DataGridView where I have made the functions for MoveUp and MoveDown for the rows. But when I swap two rows and change the selected rows, the arrow of selected row stayed at the previous place although I set the selected row on the swapped row. Can I change the arrow on the correct row? It's just a small detail but I want to know if it's possible to do it.

I have this code:

```
    private void moveUp()
    {
        if (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                int rowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
                int index = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;
                if (index == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                var temp = listApp[index];
                var temp2 = listApp[index - 1];
                listApp.Remove(temp);
                listApp.Remove(temp2);
                listApp.Insert(index-1, temp);
                listApp.Insert(index, temp2);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = listApp;
                dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Selected = false;
                //dataGridView1.Rows[index].Selected = false;
                dataGridView1.Rows[index-1].Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here the screen after swapping two rows.
[image]

Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution myself. It was enough to set dataGridView1.CurrentCell. Maybe it will be useful to someone.
The solution is here:

```
    private void moveUp()
    {
        if (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                int rowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
                int index = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;
                if (index == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                var temp = listApp[index];
                var temp2 = listApp[index - 1];
                listApp.Remove(temp);
                listApp.Remove(temp2);
                listApp.Insert(index-1, temp);
                listApp.Insert(index, temp2);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = listApp;
                dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Selected = false;                    
                dataGridView1.Rows[index-1].Selected = true;
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, index - 1];
            }
        }
    }
```